# Button Click event fires twice, even with ClickMode set to "Press"

Tags: c++-winrt

A XAML Button's Click even fires twice with a left-button mouse click.

I added  the XAML Button Property ClickMode = "Press", but that made no difference.  The Microsoft documentation for ClickMode indicates that that should have solved the problem.

I discovered this with a breakpoint in the C++ code for the Click event handler, which stopped the code twice for each button click.

XAML code within a Grid on a Page container:

```
        <Button x:Name="button_listFiles" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="List" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        Click="button_listFiles_Click" ClickMode="Press"></Button>
```

C++ Click event handler:

```
    void MainPage::button_listFiles_Click(IInspectable const& sender, RoutedEventArgs const& e) {

        MainPage::counter++;

        textBox_directoryName().Text(to_hstring(counter));
    }
```

The `MainPage::counter++;` counts the number of times the handler is called and `textBox_directoryName().Text(to_hstring(counter));` displays the result on the XAML page, used for attempted debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this problem. Perhaps you can look at the stack for both calls to see where they are coming from.

Comment: @kennykerr, It did **not** happen on the Blank App (C++/WinRT), so I looked at my code and commented out what I think is the registration of the button event, `button_listFiles().Click({ this, &MainPage::button_listFiles_Click });` in `MainPage::MainPage()` and the double firing stopped.  I am having trouble with the registration notion even after having read the Microsoft documentation.  Can I include it once for the original compile and then remove it?

Comment: The C++/WinRT Blank App template does not include a call to register the handler. I'm not a Xaml expert, but it looks like the Xaml compiler does this in the background. So it makes sense that you would receive two calls if you added your own registration on top of that.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand I can follow standard C++ and write a prototype Click event in the .h file and a definition in the .cpp file.  But, how do I determine the prototype for a Click or any event from the Microsoft documentation?  The working Click event prototype is `void b2_Click(IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& e);` but the Microsoft page for "ButtonBase.Click Event" does not have that, and only a C# example, viz., `void submitButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`, even with "C++/WinRT" selected as the language.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The docs folks are slowly working on adding documentation samples for C++. If the C# example says `object` then replace it with `Windows::Foundation::IInspectable` and input parameters are generally `const&` in C++ for efficiency.

Comment: Related... I tried to add a `PointerPressed` event for a XAML TextBlock.  The event handler in the .cpp file has as its second argument the type `PointerRoutedEventArgs` which is declared in "winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.h".  At first, I put the `#include` statement for Input.h in the .cpp file containing the event handler and got a "Linker Tools Error LNK2019".  This puzzled me since this `#include` statement came after the one for pch.h.  When I moved it to pch.h, the linker error disappeared.  Perhaps I could have added it to the .h file associated with the .cpp file, but I did not try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out, the answer is the several comments between me and Kenny Kerr.